# Why does my websites appcache not work in Safari on device, but works on desktop and in all PC browsers and Android devices?

Tags: html, ipad, safari, manifest

I cannot get appcache to work on the iPad and iPhone.

At first I thought the problem was that it was called manifest.appcache so I changed it to appcache.manifest because the Safari documentation specified that it should end in .manifest

didnt work.

When logging appcache events on a mac mini while debugging safari on the ipad I see

```
 checking
 error
```

But when I debug safari on the mac mini i see

```
 checking
 noupdate
```

It works as expected on every other non ios device i have tested and on all 5 browsers on my pc.

I have confirmed that the doc type returned is text/cache-manifest

Here is what the manifest looks like from one of the pages

https://mysite.com/Mobile/appcache.manifest?page=MyPage.aspx

```
CACHE MANIFEST
CACHE:
MyPage.aspx

Mobile.jpg

js/vendor/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js

# Resources that require the user to be online.
NETWORK:
/Mobile/appcache.manifest?page=MyPage.aspx

*
```

Also I do not see a request in the Safari debugger timeline profiler to the manifest file